# What is different between variable $a and variable $this->a in OOP PHP?

Tags: php

What is different between variable $a and variable $this->a in OOP PHP?

```
class A{
 public function example(){
  $this->a = "Hello A";
  $a = "Hello A";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little example of code to illustrate Evan's Answer

```
$myA = new A();

$myA->example();

$myA->test();

class A{

 private $a;

 public function __construct() {
  $this->a = 'Hello A';

 public function example(){
  $a = 'Hello A again';
  echo $this->a;//print 'Hello A'
  echo $a;//print 'Hello A again'
 }

 public function test() {
  echo $this->a;//print 'Hello A'
  echo $a;//E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: a
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`$this->a` represents a class variable and can be accessed from anywhere within the confines of the class whereas `$a` can only be used from within the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

`$this` is a **pseudo variable**. This pseudo-variable  is available when a method is called from within an object context. `$this` is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).

Refer **[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)**.